# Is there an email subscription plugin which allows user to select category?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email, subscription

I would like users to be able to *choose which categories* they would like to receive email notifications about when new posts are added. Is there an exsisting plug-in with this functionality.

Please don't be confused with subscribe2's global category exclusion setting. 
I don't believe subscribe2 allows users to choose categories at the time of subscribing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 :) i was going to ask the same. Does google feed burner support category wise subscription?

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 options I can think of right now:

1. [MailPress](http://www.mailpress.org/) is insanely configurable with a huge number of features for making your blog deliverable by email with many many options such as which categories to include/exclude, multiple newsletter groups etc... You can make email themes too so all of your blog's emails can be nicely styled HTML emails.
2. You can make feedburner subscriptions for any of the feeds your site can output eg. any URL on your site with `/feed/` added to the URL. The [FeedSmith extend](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedburner-setting/) plugin allows you to burn feeds for categories and tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

post notification allows selection of categories http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-notification/
There is a notification that the plugin hasn't been updated for a while but it is still working fine.